# Spring MVC : Passing XML as POST parameter truncates the XML when equals character is encountered

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, firefox-addon

In my current application i am required to pass two parameters to the REStful Spring MVC application. One parameter is an id and the other is an xml passed as a string.

```
templateXml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><template name="my_document">
.
.-- other elements of xml--
<template/>
&typeid=TYP001
```

There is a complex operation that needs to be performed before the spring container passes the parameter to the controller method. Therefore i am using a Custom HttpMessageConverter to parse the obtained XML into a Template object.

Here is the part of the Custom Converter that i am using

```
public class TemplateConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Template>{

    @Autowired
    private TemplateBuilder templateBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

    public TemplateConverter() {

        List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        super.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
    }



    @Override
    protected Template readInternal(Class<? extends Template> type, HttpInputMessage input) throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotReadableException {           
        Map<String,String> paramMap = getPostParameter(input);
        String documentTypeId = paramMap.get("typeid");

       //HERE COMES THE PROBLEM. WHAT I RECIEVE is only <?xml version 
        String templateXml = paramMap.get("templateXml");

        Template template = null;
        try {
            template = templateBuilder.build(templateXml);
            if(documentTypeId!=null){
                template.setDocumentTypeId(documentTypeId);         
            }
```

To Test this i am using FireFox Rest Client as follows

[image]

The problem is that i am just recieving `<?xml version` from http request where as the typeid parameter is perfectly mapped.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your XML contains `=`. That has special meaning in form parameters.

Comment: Yes i knew that, but eventually what needs to be done so that i can pass an xml as a form parameter and the = sign is not considered as assignment operator for form params.

Comment: I'll try and help tomorrow, but for now you should consider not sending XML as the value of a url-encoden-form-parameter.

Comment: Would look forward to your response. The only reason i am required to send xml as html form parameter is that there are other non-xml type  parameters also along with the xml which cant be included within the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by encoding the xml POST parameter using apache commons codec. So first i encoded the xml then added the encoded string as a paramter to the RESTClient. And decoded again using mentioned apache utility in the converter.

If someone has a better way please let me know